# How to read json files in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, json, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm trying to write a function, that reads json files in tensorflow. The json files have the following structure:

```
{
    "bounding_box": {
        "y": 98.5, 
        "x": 94.0, 
        "height": 197, 
        "width": 188
     }, 
    "rotation": {
        "yaw": -27.97019577026367,
        "roll": 2.206029415130615, 
        "pitch": 0.0}, 
        "confidence": 3.053506851196289, 
        "landmarks": {
            "1": {
                "y": 180.87722778320312, 
                "x": 124.47326660156205}, 
            "0": {
                "y": 178.60653686523438, 
                "x": 183.41931152343795}, 
            "2": {
                "y": 224.5936889648438, 
                "x": 141.62365722656205
}}}
```

I only need the bounding box information. There are a few examples on how to write read_and_decode-functions, and I'm trying to transform these examples into a function for json files, but there are still a lot of questions...:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):

  reader = tf.WhichKindOfReader() # ??? 
  _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example( 
      serialized_example,

      features={

          'bounding_box':{ 

              'y': tf.VarLenFeature(<whatstheproperdatatype>) ???
              'x': 
              'height': 
              'width': 

          # I only need the bounding box... - do I need to write 
          # the format information for the other features...???

          }
      })

  y=tf.decode() # decoding necessary?
  x=
  height=
  width= 

  return x,y,height,width
```

I've done research on the internet for hours, but can't find anything really detailled on how to read json in tensorflow...

Maybe someone can give me a clue...

Answer (score 6):

#### Update

The solution below does get the job done but it is not very efficient, see comments for details.

#### Original answer

You can use standard python json parsing with TensorFlow if you wrap the functions with [`tf.py_func`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html):

```py
import json
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def get_bbox(str):
    obj = json.loads(str.decode('utf-8'))
    bbox = obj['bounding_box']
    return np.array([bbox['x'], bbox['y'], bbox['height'], bbox['width']], dtype='f')

def get_multiple_bboxes(str):
    return [[get_bbox(x) for x in str]]

raw = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None])
[parsed] = tf.py_func(get_multiple_bboxes, [raw], [tf.float32])
```

Note that `tf.py_func` returns a *list of tensors* rather than just a single tensor, which is why we need to wrap `parsed` in a list `[parsed]`. If not, `parsed` would get the shape `[1, None, 4]` rather than the desired shape `[None, 4]` (where `None` is the batch size).

Using your data you get the following results:

```py
json_string = """{
    "bounding_box": {
        "y": 98.5,
        "x": 94.0,
        "height": 197,
        "width": 188
     },
    "rotation": {
        "yaw": -27.97019577026367,
        "roll": 2.206029415130615,
        "pitch": 0.0},
        "confidence": 3.053506851196289,
        "landmarks": {
            "1": {
                "y": 180.87722778320312,
                "x": 124.47326660156205},
            "0": {
                "y": 178.60653686523438,
                "x": 183.41931152343795},
            "2": {
                "y": 224.5936889648438,
                "x": 141.62365722656205
}}}"""
my_data = np.array([json_string, json_string, json_string])

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(parsed, feed_dict={raw: my_data}))
    print(sess.run(tf.shape(parsed), feed_dict={raw: my_data}))
```

```
[[  94.    98.5  197.   188. ]
 [  94.    98.5  197.   188. ]
 [  94.    98.5  197.   188. ]]
[3 4]
```

Comment: While this works, you have to worry about the GIL though.

Comment: @TimZaman I wasn't aware that [such a thing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) existed. Would you mind elaborating a bit? What is the worst case scenario of my solution?

Comment: To make a long story short, each of those lines in python code will block any other line of python code to be executed while they are running. This means your py_func cannot run concurrently with any other python code, unless you avoid GIL.

Comment: @TimZaman Would it be better to pre-process all the json objects into TFRecords before the training, store on disk, and read in batches during the training? `tf.TFRecordReader` is [written in C++](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d24e64227653ab3cab7405c79ca166063a42f0ff/tensorflow/core/kernels/tf_record_reader_op.cc) and therefore avoid GIL, right? Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Yeah that will work out great actually. Alternatively you can prepare the labels as, and put them into a `tf.constant()` array or variable, and fetch from there.

Comment: @TimZaman : Can you explain the latter part with `tf.constant()` as a solution for loading `json` data.

Comment: @Backlin : Any way I can read `json` files from within **tensorflow**?

Comment: @aspiring1 I'm not sure I understand what you mean... Reading _files_ vs just parsing json stored in string variables?

Comment: @Backlin: I meant *reading files*, as currently I have made a **two input model** , first input is an image and the second is array read from a `json or flatbuffer` file. So, I wanted to make it a single input model with `json/flatbuffer` read from within the **tensorflow model**.( I'm okay with a protocol buffer too)

Answer (score 1):

This might be skirting the issue, but you could preprocess your data with a command line tool like https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/ into a line-based data format, like csv. Would possibly be more efficient also.