# How to make tfrecords from json annotated images

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have used tensorflow object detection-api to train my own object detector.But at that time, the images were annotated using [labelimg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) which create xml file for each image.Now I have got labeled images which have json file for each image.So how I use these json files to create tfrecords.

Comment: Your question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381887/how-to-read-json-files-in-tensorflow

Comment: Nope, its not creating tfrecords

Comment: This is a good example of how to create a TFRecord file: https://gist.github.com/gvanhorn38/ac19b85a4f7b5fb9e82e04f4ac6d5566

Comment: well after hard work I have done it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I created csv files by using my own script.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import json
import pickle

def json_to_csv():
    path_to_json = 'images/train/'
    json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
    path_to_jpeg = 'images/train/'
    jpeg_files = [pos_jpeg for pos_jpeg in os.listdir(path_to_jpeg) if pos_jpeg.endswith('.jpeg')]
    fjpeg=(list(reversed(jpeg_files)))
    n=0
    csv_list = []
    labels=[]
    for j in json_files:
        data_file=open('images/train/{}'.format(j))   
        data = json.load(data_file)
        width,height=data['display_width'],data['display_height']
        for item in data["items"]:
            box = item['bounding_box']
            if item['upc']!='None':
                name=item['upc']
                labels.append(name)
                xmin=box['left']
                ymin=box['top']
                xmax=box['right']
                ymax=box['bottom']
                value = (fjpeg[n],
                         width,
                         height,
                         name,
                         xmin,
                         ymin,
                         xmax,
                         ymax
                         )
                csv_list.append(value)
          n=n+1
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    csv_df = pd.DataFrame(csv_list, columns=column_name)
    labels_train=list(set(labels))
    with open("train_labels.txt", "wb") as fp:   #Pickling
        pickle.dump(labels_train, fp)
    return csv_df

def main():
    for directory in ['train']:
        csv_df = json_to_csv()
        csv_df.to_csv('data/{}_labels.csv'.format(directory), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted json to csv.')

main()
```

Then I use [this](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py) script to create tfrecords.

Answer (score 0):

We have [some documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) on the subject.

Note that labelimg should produce outputs similar to the PASCAL VOC datasets we use, so those scripts may also be of use.

Comment: I have used labelimg and i know it produce PASCAL VOC. The question how to convert a jason file in to tfrecords